# Change font size based on Accessibility Settings in Appcelerator Studio

Tags: titanium, accessibility, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I am working on Titanium application which I am giving support for Android and iPhone. My goal is to change the overall app's font size whenever  we change font size from Accessibility Settings. **(Settings->General-> Accessibility->Larger Text->Setting maximum size)**

Currently font size change is reflecting only in AlertDialog. I want to happen changes in all elements like Label, button, listview etc.

In android, font size is reflecting when I am setting font size from Accessibility.

Could you please suggest any solution for this!

Thanks !!

Comment: Could anyone have idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use font size in sp (scale-independant pixel)

```
"#myLabel": {
    font: {
         fontSize: '14sp'
    }
}
```

That would make it work